# Dynamic groups in Postgresql data

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 database with a table containing measurement data, which contains setpoint information. For example temperature setpoints. The measurements are taken when at a setpoint, after which the following setpoint will be set. A setpoint can be reached multiple times, e.g. -25, 25, 75, 125, 75, 25 degree Celcius. In this case 25 and 75 degree Celcius are reached multiple times.
Now I want to group the data per setpoint, but not group data together of another setpoint that has the same value but is reached at a later point in time.

Example data:

```
| id | setpoint | value |<dyn.group>|
| 1 | -25 | 5.324 | 1
| 2 | -25 | 6.343 | 1
| 3 | -25 | 6.432 | 1
| 4 |  25 | 3.432 | 2
| 5 |  25 | 4.472 | 2
| 6 |  25 | 6.221 | 2
| 7 |  75 | 5.142 | 3
| 8 |  75 | 7.922 | 3
| 9 |  75 | 3.832 | 3
|10 | 125 | 8.882 | 4
|11 | 125 | 9.742 | 4
|12 | 125 | 7.632 | 4
|13 |  75 | 5.542 | 5
|14 |  75 | 2.452 | 5
|15 |  75 | 1.332 | 5
|16 |  25 | 3.232 | 6
|17 |  25 | 4.132 | 6
|18 |  25 | 5.432 | 6
```

Normal group by clauses will fail, because setpoint can be there multiple times, but should not be put together.
Looking with LEAD and LAG to the previous/next values is also not desired, because changes will most likely be similar (e.g. if setpoint 75 is repeated, then most likely the step from 25->75 will also be repeated).

The expected outcome is the 4th column (`<dyn.group>`). With that column I can for example average on these groups.

Comment: What is your expected result based on that data? ([edit] your question)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a [custom aggregation function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xaggr.html) to generate the "group index" value and then a "group by" clause in that value.